# SOS does not support the current target architecture

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windbg, dump, freeze

I am trying to use windbg to research a hang dump file created on an x64 machine for our x86 process. This is a 4.0 x86 application, so just to get an unmanaged stack, I had to do the following:

```
.loadby sos clr
.load wow64exts
!sw
kL
```

However, everytime I try to get the managed stack via `!clrstack` I get the error in the title. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running WinDbg on a Windows 8 machine? I get the same error message only in a Windows 8 machine. If I dump memory to a file I cannot run SOS even if I do !wow64exts.sw to switch to 32-bit mode. I can however execute SOS if I attach to the process...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe you will have to use the 32-bit task manager, located in   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe to get a 32-bit dump.

More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx

Comment: So, there is no way to use the current dump?

Comment: One comment in the link above mentions running !wow64exts.sw, which may let you run stack related commands, like !clrstack. Never tried that myself as i've been able to grab a new dump instead.

Comment: I am going to leave this open for a day or so to see if anybody has an answer that isn't that I am doa, otherwise I will accept this one

Comment: @BenG: http://web.archive.org/web/20160205021908/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine/

Answer (score 21):

As others have said already, this can be caused by a 64 bit application (like the default Task Manager, for example) creating a dump file of a 32 bit process.

I was able to resolve the problem using the soswow64 WinDbg extension from [poizan42 on GitHub](https://github.com/poizan42/soswow64). I've found it through [this blog entry](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/experimental-use-of-64-bit-dump-of-32-bit-net-process-in-windbg/), which also provides some more detailed information about the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should be the answer now, but I may be a bit biased ;)

Comment: @poizan42 Thanks a lot for soswow64, it had made my work so much easier!

Comment: @poizan42: That is a great tool which should have much more attention. It works also with Windbg of 10.0.17713.1000 of the latest platform SDK. Great Work!

Answer (score 6):

I've always followed the recommendation of the bitness matching but never knew exactly why until I came across this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx which states:

> "The DAC has a standardized interface and is used by the debugger to
>   obtain information about the state of those abstractions, for example,
>   the managed heap. It is essential to use the DAC that matches the CLR
>   version and the architecture of the process or crash dump you want to
>   inspect."

AND

> "Note that the DAC is a native DLL and must be loaded into the program
>   that uses ClrMD. If the dump or the live process is 32-bit, you must
>   use the 32-bit version of the DAC, which, in turn, means that your
>   inspection program needs to be 32-bit as well. The same is true for
>   64-bit processes. Make sure that your program’s platform matches what
>   you are debugging."

Answer (score 3):

There is one more option that worked for me: 
- I had crash dump of a 64 bit process. 
- So, first, I needed SOS.dll and mscordacwks.dll from the machine (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319) where the dump was taken.
- Based on two msdn articles (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff562263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff540665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I loaded CLR this way:

```
.cordll -u -ve -I clr -lp <path to SOS.dll & mscordacwks.dll>
```

After this, !threads worked. I think, same should apply for 32-bit crash dumps.