# Windbg loadin sos for UWP x64 dump (.loadby/.load)

Tags: c#, windbg, dump, sos

Usually, when I debug .NET applications I use .loadby command, depending on the Clr version:

```
.loadby sos mscorwks / .loadby sos clr
```

I am trying to debug a dump which is taken from x64 UWP application, but I don’t see clr or mscrowks between loaded modules.
Is there a special way for sos loading for UWP apps?

When I load the sos manually, this is my output:

```
0:000> .load  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll
0:000> !DumpHeap
SOS does not support the current target architecture.
```

Couldn’t find anything helpful online…

I can see that CoreClr loaded here:

```
0x1df39d116b0: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23819.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\CoreCLR.dll
      Base   0x7ffa65140000  EntryPoint  0x7ffa651417d0  Size        0x005b5000    DdagNode     0x1df39d13320
      Flags  0x000822cd  TlsIndex    0x00000000  LoadCount   0xffffffff    NodeRefCount 0x00000000
             <unknown>
             LDRP_LOAD_NOTIFICATIONS_SENT
             LDRP_IMAGE_DLL
             LDRP_PROCESS_ATTACH_CALLED
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422577/sos-does-not-support-the-current-target-architecture ?

Comment: When you see "x64" back in the CoreCLR pathname then you can safely assume that it is **not** an x86 app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which version of sos and clr/mscorwks.dll to load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226337/which-version-of-sos-and-clr-mscorwks-dll-to-load)

Comment: It is an x64 dump, I made a typo ( I am encounter the same issue regardless x64 to x86)

Comment: @Blam I don't think it's related, I took this dump using procexp (which makes valid dumps for x86) - although it's a 64 bit dump (sorry for confusion)